# Solve $ \left|\frac{x}{x+2}\right|\leq 2 $

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am experiencing a little confusion in answering a problem on Absolute Value inequalities which I just started learning. This is the problem: Solve:
$$ 
\left|\frac{x}{x+2}\right|\leq 2
$$
The answer is given to be $x\leq-4$ or $x \geq-1$

This is my attempt to solve the problem:

By dividing, $\left|\frac{x}{x+2}\right|\leq 2$ is equivalent to $\left |1-\frac{2}{x+2}\right|\leq2$ which is also equivalent to $\left |\frac{2}{x+2}-1\right|\leq2$

So, $-2\leq\frac{2}{x+2}-1\leq2$ which is equivalent to $-\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{1}{x+2}\leq\frac{3}{2}$

Case 1: $x+2>0$. Solving $-\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{1}{x+2}\leq\frac{3}{2}$, I get $x\geq-4$ and $x\geq-\frac{4}{3}$ which is essentially $x\geq-\frac{4}{3}$.

Case 2: $x+2<0$. Solving $-\frac{1}{2}\times(x+2)\geq{1}\geq\frac{3}{2}\times(x+2)$, I get $x\leq-4$ and $x\leq-\frac{4}{3}$ which is essentially $x\leq-4$.

So, the solutions are: $x\leq-4$ or $x\geq-\frac{4}{3}$.

I couldn't get $x \geq-1$ as a solution. Did I do anything wrong? The book I am using is Schaum's Outlines-Calculus. Another question I would like to ask is that am I using 'and' and 'or' correctly in the above attempt to solve the problem? I have had this problem many times.

Comment: Your answer is correct, the one in the book isn't true.

Comment: @Workaholic Ah. Thank you very much!

Comment: A quick check is by plugging the interval endpoints. $|\frac{-4}{-4+2}|=2$. But $|\frac{-1}{-1+2}|\ne2$ while $|\frac{-4/3}{-4/3+2}|=2$.

Comment: Simply remember mod gets off with +,- sign so your approach and answer seems fine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a very helpful method. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Understood. Thank you!

Comment: I would say your solution is the best. Very simple and methodical, straight to the point. Good job, +1.

Comment: @MPW Thank you for the encouraging words!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have
$$
\lvert x \rvert \leq 2\lvert x+2\rvert.
$$
If $x \geq 0$, then $x + 2 > 0$. And then the equation reads $x \leq 2x + 4$ implying that $x \geq -4 $. This in all gives you the solutions $x \geq 0$.

If $x\in [-2, 0)$, then the equation becomes $-x \leq 2x + 4$. So $-4\leq 3x$. So $\frac{-4}{3} \leq x$. In all you get $x\in [-4/3, 0)$.

Now the last case is where $x <-2$. Then $-x \leq -2x - 4$. So $4 \leq -x$. So $-4\geq x$. This gives the set of solutions $(-\infty, -4]$.

Putting it all together gives you the closed interval:
$$
(-\infty, -4] \cup [-4/3,\infty)
$$

It looks like your solution is correct.

Comment: I never viewed it that way! I was so intent on having $x$ on the left-hand side. Thank you sharing another method to solve this!

Comment: @ChrisJWelly: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

the case $x+2>0$, you do not need to solve $-1/2\le 1/(x+2)\leftarrow x+2>0$.

the case $x+2<0$, the inequality you solve it's not the original one. 
It should be $-1/2 \le 1/(x+2) \le 3/2$ and in case $x+2<0\rightarrow 1/(x+2)<3/2$, so it's just $-1/2 \le 1/(x+2)$.

Think it simply.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on the first case. I am actually self-learning this, and I was following the worked examples as I am still rather unsure.
It's my mistake on the second one, sorry! I meant to have multiplied everything by $x+2$ hence the change in sign.I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that, $$\left|\frac{x}{x+2}\right|\le 2$$$$\iff |x|\le 2|x+2| $$
Notice, $x=-2$ & $x=0$ are two critical points on the number line. Now, let's consider the following cases,

Case 1: If $\color{blue}{x\le -2}$ $$-x\le -2(x+2)\iff x\le -4\ \ \ ({\text{True}})$$
$$\implies \color{red}{x\in(-\infty, -4]}$$ 
Case 2: If $\color{blue}{-2<x<0}$ $$-x\le 2(x+2)\iff x\ge -\frac{4}{3}\ \ \ $$ 
but, $x<0$ hence, $$-\frac{4}{3}<x<0\iff \color{red}{x\in\left[-\frac{4}{3}, 0\right)}$$

Case 3: If $\color{blue}{x\ge 0}$ $$x\le 2(x+2)\iff x\ge -4\ \ \ $$ 
but, $x\ge 0$ hence, $$x\ge 0\iff \color{red}{x\in\left[0, \infty\right)}$$
Hence, the combining the above cases, the complete solution is given as 
$$\color{red}{x\in (-\infty, -4]\cup \left[-\frac{4}{3}, \infty\right) }$$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

As long as $x\in\Bbb{R}$, you can consider $|\frac{x}{x+2}|$ as $(\frac{x}{x+2})\text{sign}(\frac{x}{x+2})$

Comment: This is a way I never would have thought of. Usually the sign function is unusable, but here it is excellent because you are dealing with inequalities

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problem systematically. If you want to solve $|f(x)|\le c$ or $|f(x)|\geq c$ (for some constant $c\geq 0$), you have to study the sign of $f(x)$. It can be longer for "simple" problem like yours, but it has the advantage to always give you the solution for more complex ones.

For your particular example, we have $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+2}$, which is:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & &-2 & &0 & &\\
\hline
x & - &- & - &0 &+\\
x+2 & - & 0 & + & + & +\\
\hline
f(x) & + &\nexists &- & 0 &+
\end{array}$$
Which means that $f(x)\geq 0$ when $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup[0,+\infty)$ and $f(x)\le 0$ when $x\in(-2,0]$.

1) For $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup[0,+\infty)$, $f(x)\geq 0$, so that
$$\left\vert\frac{x}{x+2}\right\vert=\frac{x}{x+2}$$
and the inequation is 
$$\frac{x}{x+2}\le 2\iff\frac{-x-4}{x+2}\le 0$$
which gives:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & &-4 & &-2 & &\\
\hline
-x-4 & + &0 & - &- &-\\
x+2 & - & - & - & 0 & +\\
\hline
 & - &0 &+ & \nexists &-
\end{array}$$
and the solutions are $$\left[(-\infty,-4]\cup(-2,+\infty)\right]\cap\left[(-\infty,-2)\cup[0,+\infty)\right]=(-\infty,-4]\cup[0,+\infty)$$

2) For $x\in]-2,0]$, $f(x)\le 0$, so that
$$\left\vert\frac{x}{x+2}\right\vert=-\frac{x}{x+2}$$
and the inequation is 
$$\frac{x}{x+2}\le 2\iff\frac{-3x-4}{x+2}\le 0$$
which gives:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & &-2 & &-4/3 & &\\
\hline
-3x-4 & + &+ & + &0 &-\\
x+2 & - & 0 & + & + & +\\
\hline
 & - &\nexists &+ & 0 &-
\end{array}$$
and the solutions are $$\left[(-\infty,-2)\cup[-4/3,+\infty)\right]\cap(-2,0]=[-4/3,0]$$

And the final solution is given by $$\left\vert\frac{x}{x+2}\right\vert\le 2\iff x\in(-\infty,-4]\cup[0,+\infty)\cup[-4/3,0]=(-\infty,-4]\cup[-4/3,+\infty)$$

I know it seems long in this particular case but it is good to have a general method for this kind of problem.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand your notations in 'x∈]−∞,−2[∪[0,+∞[x∈]−∞,−2[∪[0,+∞[ and f(x)≤0f(x)≤0 when x∈]−2,0]x∈]−2,0].' and '∄'. I understand usage of [ or ] and ( or ) as intervals though.

Comment: Sorry, $]\cdot , \cdot[$ is equivalent to $(\cdot,\cdot)$. In my country, we almost never use $($ or $)$ for that purpose. I'll modify my answer, so that it is clearer for this community.

Comment: This is not more general than OP's solution and is unnecessarily complicated. If you look carefully, you have reduced it to exactly the same pair of inequalities that OP solved directly without resorting to sign charts. I do encourage students to understand and use sign charts, but in this case it is not really worth the effort, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not interesting here. But if you want to solve $|f(x)|\le c$ or $|f(x)|\geq c$ for more complicated $f$, it is good, in my opinion, to have a general method.

Comment: Wow. Took me a while to understand the solution. I do hope this technique will be useful when solving more complicated problems. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. But as MPM said, it is unnecessarily complicated in this particular case. It can be more interesting in a problem like $| 1$.